# Jquery progressbar not showing up

Tags: php, jquery, progress-bar

I have jquery script in a php file:

```
print "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css\" />                                                                                                       
 <script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js\"></script>                                                                                                                                          
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/resources/demos/style.css\" />";


print "<script>                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 $(function() {                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 $( \"#p\" ).progressbar({ max: 10 });                                                                                                                                                                              
 $( \"#p\" ).progressbar({                                                                                                                                                                                          
 value:" . $_SESSION['pagenum'] . "});                                                                                                                                                                              
 $( '#p' ).progressbar( 'enable' );                                                                                                                                                                                 
 });                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 </script>";
```

And I have html that looks like this:

```
print "<div id = 'p'></div>";
```

But the progressbar is not showing up. I am printing the session variable so I know it exits. Any reasons why the progressbar is not happening? 
Thanks!

Comment: are you including jQuery.js file anywhere in your code? You know that jQuery-UI won't work without jQuery.js right ?

Comment: are you including the core jQuery library? http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Comment: I included that. Still not working!

Comment: Suggestion: Put your JS script above your CSS.

Comment: I also noticed you're using sessions. May or may not be relevant as many do not do this, is `session_start();` inside all your .php files?

Comment: I put JS code above CSS still not working.

Comment: yes session_start() is inside all php files

Comment: You could also try renaming your `div id` to something else. jQuery may be confusing it for the `<p>` tag. And/or try escaping your div to `print "<div id = \"p\"></div>";`

Comment: changed the name, still not working :(

Comment: Hard to say at this point without seeing your entire codes.

Comment: Usually, JS/jQuery is placed within the `<head>`. Where are yours located?

Comment: Might even need `$(document).ready jquery` in there somewhere. Not 100% sure.